# I just sent ETH to an ICO. tx receipt failed. How can I get my funds back?

Tags: transactions, erc-20

I incorrectly sent Ethereum direct to an ICO address instead of an ERC-20 Compliant wallet.  I can see the transaction has failed however not sure how to recover my funds. Can anybody please help me?

https://etherscan.io/tx/0x06f96d44cc0f97e8b38a0b864e7af9b000b200e3346f9319ba52c3e5bc068aab

Many thanks
NR

Answer (score 1):

From the etherscan page it looks like you did not send any funds.

You did expend gas on trying the transaction, but this is not recoverable. The gas cost is what you pay to process the transaction.

Answer (score 0):

As @trejas points out, you did not spend any funds, but you did spend gas, which is the cost of processing Ethereum transactions, and the gas cost is NOT recoverable.

**Please note:** By setting such a high gas limit, in your case **`500000`,** you leave yourself open to an expensive loss, in the event of a failed transaction. The actual cost of that kind of transaction, would have probably been less than **`200000`** gas, which would have cut your loss down from **`$15.20`** to **`$6.08`** in the event of a failure.

To improve your chances of a successful transaction in the future, I'd recommend you first check the gas rates at **https://ethgasstation.info/.**